# How can I view how page will be working on salesforce app on my computer without installing salesforce app and without using browser extensions?

Tags: salesforce

Is there any way to do view how page looks like on Salesforce mobile app while I am on my computer and I can't install this app?

Comment: Have you tried installing Salesforce1 Simulator in your computer?